# coxph Error weights must be finite. How do I return this model?

Tags: r

I have run a cox regression model below

```
allcause_cox<-coxph(Surv(allcause_time, allcause)~centgroup, data=fulldata)
```

This has run fine. However I want to return robust standard error. Therefore I have introduced the

```
cluster(parity)
```

term into the model, where parity is another variable in my data set. However this won't run. It returns the error

```
> allcause_cox<-coxph(Surv(allcause_time, allcause)~centgroup, data=fulldata, cluster(parity))

Error in coxph(Surv(allcause_time, allcause)~centgroup, data=fulldata, :
   weights must be finite
```

Is there a solution to this? I have read about the weight term which can be added but I'm not sure what this does.

Answer (score 0):

cluster is in the wrong place, the command should read

```
allcause_cox<-coxph(Surv(allcause_time, allcause)~centgroup+cluster(parity), data=fulldata)
```